# Yii framework 2.0 Role based access control PhpManager

Tags: php, yii2, rbac

Working with Yii framework 2.0 I would like to work with Role Based Access Control using PhpManager. Follow the documentation I configure that as following.

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\PhpManager',
        ],
    ],
];
```

In my controller class I just print that object out to see how it looks like.

```
print_r(\Yii::$app->authManager);
```

I've got the following error:

```
ReflectionException

Class yii\rbac\PhpManager does not exist
```

What might cause this error? I think because I miss the PhpManager component, but I am not sure. If I need to add this component, how can I do that? If it is not about missing this component. What might cause this error?

Answer (score 1):

Update your `composer.json` file like below:

```
"require": {
    "yiisoft/yii2": "*"
},
```

It'll be fixed.

Comment: After doing that I get the following error: Unknown Method – yii\base\UnknownMethodException.
Calling unknown method: yii\web\UrlManager::addRules(). I didn't use any UrlManager::addRules() in my code. Note that this error only occurs when I am on development environment.

Comment: @OConnor there are some issues in upgrading the yii 2 (any version,such as RC,Beta and so on...). You should read the following document: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/UPGRADE.md